# Rails: Bootstrap navbar collapsed by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bootstrap-4

After updating [bootstrap rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem) from **4.0.0.alpha6** to **4.0.0.beta**, default behavior of `navbar` is not working as before. By default links within it is hidden behind the button, even though for full screen.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

How should I fix it?

Comment: this appears when you use bootstrap alpha css and js with bootstrap 4.00 beta

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I reverted from beta to alpha: `gem 'bootstrap', '4.0.0.alpha6'`

Comment: did my answer work for you?

Comment: I am not externally downloading bootstrap, it is getting handled by ruby package manager, so your answer doesn't fit in the context.

Answer (score 1):

For **beta** version:

> Navbars require a wrapping `.navbar` with
>   `.navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl}` for responsive collapsing and color
>   scheme classes.

So instead of:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
```

It should be:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
```

[Source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that you are using bootstrap 4.00 beta css and js files.

Default navbar example of bootstrap beta works in snippet and this fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/s4qvqdbc/ try to change screen size in jsfiddle then you will see collapsed and uncollapsed form of it

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```